# *Nix ls Command in Java

Tags: java, shell

Anyone aware of a method/class/library that will allow me to easily reproduce the results of the *nix ls -l command in Java? Calling ls directly is not an option due to platform independence.

eg.
$ls -l myprogram.exe

-rwxrwxrwx 1 auser None 1261568 Nov 15 17:41 C:\myprogram.exe

Comment: To clarify, can you say exactly what part(s) of the 'ls -l' output you need?  For example, if you just needed the file size and modification date, then a plain old java.io.File object should do the trick.  But if you want the permission information too, you're getting into platform-specific territory there and will require more sophisticated classes.

Comment: Excellent point. I'm porting an existing ksh script, so I was hoping to find a method out in the Ether to drop in and use. Absent that I will probably just take what's available in java.io.File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This provides what you are looking for:](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/jEdit/bsh/commands/dir.java.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [tutorial on getting a directory listing in java with sample source code](http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0111.shtml).

Comment: Here is the Javadoc for the File class that is covered the tutorial that Asaph mentions.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of `ls -R ~`, which lists files recursively starting in the home directory:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ListDir {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File root;
        if (args.length > 0) root = new File(args[0]);
        else root = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        ls(root); 
    }

    /** iterate recursively */
    private static void ls(File f) { 
        File[] list = f.listFiles();
        for (File file : list) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) ls(file);
            else System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`java.nio.file`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score -1):

I think we don't have ready to use Java class in java stadard library.
But you can develop a tool like *nix ls -l tool by using classes in java.io package.