# How to search a node in outline view in swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, outline-view

I have implemented the [outline view](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component) in my application which consist of 200 node. How can I search a specific node and expand it ?

I have also looked `breadthFirstEnumeration()` and `depthFirstEnumeration()` method of `DefaultMutableTreeNode` but could not find equivalent method in Outline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach depends on the `TreeModel` used to construct your `OutlineModel`. In the `FileTreeModel` cited, `getRoot()` returns an arbitrary `File` representing the root of a subtree in a hierarchical file system. This subtree can be searched recursively as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009376/230513). Instead of printing the results, you would accumulate the `File` instances representing the path into an array. That array would be used to construct a `TreePath`. Given such a `treePath`, you can reveal the corresponding node in a manner analogous to that shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8210759/230513).

```
outline.expandPath(treePath);
outline.scrollRectToVisible(getPathBounds(treePath));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing me the idea. Although I am not using FileTreeModel, I am using my own custom model and I will implement is in my way. Thanks again